# True of False? If covering space admits hyperbolic metric then base space admits hyperbolic metric.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, metric-spaces, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $p:X \rightarrow B$ be a covering map. Is it true that if $X$ admits hyperbolic metric then $B$ admits hyperbolic metric?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

False. Consider the covering of the torus $\mathbb{T}^2$ by the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. You can put a metric of constant curvature $-1$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by identifying it with any model of the hyperbolic plane but any metric on $\mathbb{T}^2$ must be either flat or have points of positive, zero and negative curvature.